# Implode JSON object

Tags: php, json

Below given, is my code:

```
$array=$_POST[number];
$jstring = json_decode($array,true);

$sa = "'".implode("','",$jstring)."'";
```

The error is given below.

```
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed <root> on line <line no>
```

`Number` is a `JSON` object. Can someone Help me out? please. *Thanks in Advance.*

**Edit:**
Number is a `JSON` string. I need it to be comma separated. Number holds the phone numbers from a mobiles contact. I need each number to be used in an `Sql Query`.

---

**Problem Fixed:**
I fixed this problem. Sharing with others.

```
$array = $_POST[number];
$json = (array) json_decode($array,true);

$sa = "'" . implode(',', $json) . "'";
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$number`?

Comment: Have you `var_dump`ed `$array` to check its contents?

Comment: `$_POST[number];` should be `$_POST['number'];` though? surely..

Comment: Indeed @FDL, it should be `'number'`, or `$number` when `$number` contains `'number'` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble debugging, use var_dump or even in combination with gettype() around the argument you're trying to implode. You never need to implode JSON objects, they are decoded perfectly find. Make sure you know the difference between CSV (Comma Separated Values) and JSON.

CSV:

```
Believe,it,or,not,I,am,CSV
```

Whereas JSON:

```
{"itbetrue":"ibeJSON"}
{"iam":["an","array","in","JSON"]}
```

If you're trying to get a JSON decoded array's values, use it like this:

```
$csv = implode(',', array_values($json));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$json = $_POST['number']; // $json is a json string
$object = json_decode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); // stdClass => array
echo implode("','", $object); // This works if $object is not multiple array
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the value $_POST[number] is coming as a json format before trying to decode it ... can u var_dump it and check

Comment: True! :) Again, use 'number', since `number` is deprecated as of... if I were to guess 4.2.

Comment: number is a Jason object which hols numbers from mobile contact. I was able to append the data to a file.

Comment: use this once $array=array($_POST[number]);
    $sa = "'".implode(',',$jstring)."'";